# Spring mongodb dbref one to many how implement

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mongo

```
    @Document(collection = "users")
    public class User {

        @Id
        private String id;

        @DBRef(lazy = true)
        private Set<User> following = new HashSet<>();
}
```

For example i do somethink like that

```
User one = new User();
User two = new User();
one.follow(two);
userRepository.save(one);
```

For this moment, all working right. But after that

```
two.follow(one);
userRepository.save(two);
```

When i try to get one of two user i have hung program, 
i think its couse that:
User one loaded with list that contains user two, but user two contains list with user one that contains list with this user and finally i had loop.
Is the best way create additional Document for link two objects???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your document has a `DBRef` then when it is loaded so are all documents referred to by any `DBRef`'s.

So if `User one` has a `DBRef` to `User two`
and `User two` has a `DBRef` to `User one`

the result will be an infinite loop (resulting in your hang).

i.e. One loads two, two then loads one which in turn loads two...

(1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2)

Although i cannot think of a reason you want this in any situation it is possible to achienve this kind of referencing using a technique called `Manual Referencing`.

This basically means include the _id of any Users associated with any other users. that way when you load a user you only load a list of Strings which can be used to load each user out of the database.

**Note:** If you delete a user you will have to find all occurences of that user in the "userReference" field and remove them.

Comment: Thx, great answer ;)

Comment: @BabyGluk thanks, see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#manual-references for more information!